# How to restore database with ib_log0, ib_log1 and ibdata1 files in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

We have a Mysql5.5 running on Windows server 2008 from past 4 years.

Recently we have moved ib* files to new locations because of space constraint in c drive.

When we started the Mysql it created all 3 ib* files in the default location. We could able to see the databases and tables through sql workbench.  But when selecting data it says `<schema>.<table>` doesn't exists.  So we copied back all 3 ib* files back to default location.  But the service is not getting started. Getting error code 1067.

[image]

And My Error Log is as below.

```
160603 12:23:33 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160603 12:23:34 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160603 12:23:34 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
160603 12:23:34 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160603 12:23:34 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 753.0M
160603 12:23:34 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160603 12:23:34  InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory. It may also be you have created a subdirectory
InnoDB: of the same name as a data file.
InnoDB: File name .\ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Running service as default LocalSystem.

And checked **administrator** login has full rights on **data** folder.

Can anyone suggest how to get back my tables with data using the old ib* files which I moved to new location.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mysql #1064 is syntax error, a problem with a statement, not service. Please add the full error message, or better the output from error log. Next time do a proper backup before meddling with data files. Windows shortcuts are not symlinks (NTFS can do these but you need the right command).

Comment: @jkavalik, added service start error snapshot along with ErrorLog

Comment: *" The error means mysqld does not have the access rights or the directory."* - that sounds quite specific, you need to allow access to these files for the user account MySQL uses.

Comment: @jkavalik, we have only administrator login. and service will be run with this account only.

Comment: Is the file maybe set to `read-only`?

Comment: @jkavalik, Yes the file is in readonly. thanks for your support. If you add answer i will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part of the error log shows your instance is not able to `open()` the `ibdata1` file (for reading and writing).

First to check in such situation are user rights. In Windows another possibility is the `read-only` file attribute which can block writes too.